# iPad doesn’t know it is online unless connected to a hotspot from my mobile

Tags: ipad, wifi

My iPad 6 (running 12.4) doesn’t seem to know it’s online.

I inherited this iPad from my dad (who had no troubles with it, though I’m not sure he’d notice) and reinstalled it as my own. But things haven’t worked right since.

The situation is strange. Some apps think they are offline (mail, outlook mail) and literally NEVER connect to the internet, whereas others work normally (gmail).

This isn’t an external WiFi issue, the same problem persists if I use WiFi at home, work, or at a Starbucks. I even wiped it clean, installed factory settings and resynced it with my own profile,  but the issue persists.

Interestingly, when I connect to a hotspot, I can use a few more apps, but some NEVER work (iOS mail, outlook mail, OmniFocus)

Short of going to the Apple Store, do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please share your network specially DNS settings? Seems like you’re not configuring network properly.

Comment: Actually, I solved it by uninstalling my ProtonVPN...!